# ThingWorx: Join table in mashup grid

Tags: thingworx

I have data model where `car` has some `sensors`. Sensor is a `Thing` alias its object with properties and cannot be represented as single column, I want sensor be represented as a just `name` property of Sensor Object. How could I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you build another service which returns the Infotable that you need, I see that's an Infotable, Inside an Infotable, this will make it so difficult to manage it through Mashups.

Best Regards,
Carles.

Comment: Carles Call, could you expose some approximate code snippet of such service, please?

Comment: I asked separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721805/thingworx-customize-getimplementingthings-service

Answer (score 0):

1. Select `configure grid columns` from the arrow icon displayed on the grid.
2. [List of grid columns will be show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R63sh.png).
3. Select/deselect the required variable to be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

when you want to see only name in your Grid you can use configure Grid Columns of Grid